# Jquery each loop in rows not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to get each value when a button clicked.
what i missed?

```
//add row
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    $(".oItem:last").clone().insertAfter(".oItem:last");                                
});

//submit
$("#btnCalc").click(function(){
  $("[id^=txtItemName]").each(function(){
    alert($("#txtItemName").val());
  });                       
});
```

my fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/k5ndm840/3/

thanks

Comment: **ID SHOULD BE UNIQUE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).val();` as you will be getting `this` => `current` element in each iteration. In `each` callback, `this` refers to the `element`

`$("#txtItemName")` will always select first element having `id` as `txtItemName`

Try this:

```js
$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
  $(".oItem:last").clone().insertAfter(".oItem:last");
});
$("#btnCalc").click(function() {
  $("[id^=txtItemName]").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
<button id="btnCalc">Submit</button>

<div class="masterItem">
  <div class="row oItem">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Quantity</span>
          <input id="txtItemName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="put random number here" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/k5ndm840/4/)

**Edit:** As per the `www` standards, *There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.* [[Ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)]. As you are dealing with `attribute` selector, you are not facing any issue but **ID MUST BE UNIQUE**

**Edit:** To find another child under the parent element, use `.closest()` to find the `parent element` and `.find()` to select child of the parent.

Try this:

```js
$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
  $(".oItem:last").clone().insertAfter(".oItem:last");
});

$("#btnCalc").click(function() {
  $("[id^=txtItemName]").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    alert($(this).closest(".form-group").find('[id=txtTwo]').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
<button id="btnCalc">Submit</button>

<div class="masterItem">
  <div class="row oItem">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold;color:#330099">Quantity</span>
          <input id="txtItemName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="put random number here" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <input id="txtTwo" placeholder="second input">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks rayon, how about if i have another field beside and loop alerting them? https://jsfiddle.net/k5ndm840/7/

Answer (score 3):

You are using the **same ID** for each new field being added. You should use class instead of id in your case as id has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying to access the elements with id it will always give the first element matching the selector criteria.

```
$("#txtItemName").val()
```

This will always give the value of first matching element. Try to do like this.

```
//submit
$("#btnCalc").click(function(){
    $("[id^=txtItemName]").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });                       
});
```